# why I can access private method from outside in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it allowed to call derived class' private virtual method via pointer of base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991267/why-is-it-allowed-to-call-derived-class-private-virtual-method-via-pointer-of-b)

Recently, I met a strange question, plz refer to following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        virtual void disp() {
            cout<<"A disp"<<endl;
        }

};

class B : public A
{
    private:
        void disp() {
            cout<<"B disp"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.disp();

    A *b = new B();
    b->disp();
}
```

and the output is:

```
A disp
B disp
```

I'm wondering why pointer b can access disp()? It's private! Isn't it?

Comment: It isn't for the class you're accessing it through

Comment: `A::disp` is public; that's the only `disp` that main is accessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

disp() is public since you're calling it through an A* and disp() is declared as public in A. Since it is virtual, B's version of disp gets called, but that doesn't affect whether it's public or private.

Answer (score 1):

It's by language design. However it's a bad practice to strengthen methods protection level when deriving

Comment: It's also good practice to declare your inherited virtual methods as `virtual`, in my opinion.

Comment: @Aesthete: agreed. Easier to read